# dynamically allocate an **pointer in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm trying to learn how to allocate a 2d array within a struct, but it keeps getting a segfault. I know how to allocate a 2d array outside of a struct but i don't know why its getting a segfault when i move it into a struct.

```
/*program to allocate a 2d array and fill it with 0's and then print it.*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct stuff
{
   int **arr;
}stuff;

int main()
{
  stuff x;
  int i,j;//loop counters
  //allocate 2d array
  x.arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);
  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    x.arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
//intialize 2d array to 0
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
       x.arr[i][j] = 0;
//print 2d array
  for(i=0; i<4; i++);
    for(j=0; j< 4; j++)
       printf("arr[%d][%d] = %d \n", i ,j ,x.arr[i][j]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding the calls to malloc: 1) in C, the returned value  should not be cast.  2) the returned value should always be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon in your last `i` loop. This causes you access wrong memory address, as `j` loop runs with `i` value of 4, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Moral of the story: ALWAYS put in the braces on if-else blocks.

Comment: ugh it was that easy. i feel dumb

Answer (score 1):

Change `for(i=0; i<4; i++);` into `for(i=0; i<4; i++)` and everything works well